# How can I split a large file into smaller parts on Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, unix

I want to split a large file ~9 GB by lines, I know split command in UNIX but is there a similar command for Windows?

Comment: Not by lines but you may split it using zip

Answer (score 2):

Check the possible duplicate indicated by Ryan above, but I would also recommend [Cygwin](http://cygwin.org/) which will give you `split` and a range of other Linux commands.